# .Net Functions support in Alibaba Cloud

Tags: serverless, alibaba-cloud, serverless-architecture

I plan to migrate my azure functions to Alibaba Function compute. I see there is .Net  SDK available from Alibaba but function compute documentation doesn't state or provide examples for .Net.

Do they support?

Answer (score 1):

To get started, Alibaba Cloud can be used with various programming languages for the purpose of Function Compute.

According to the following [article](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/74712.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.b99.30.742440cbhoTA07), Alibaba Cloud supports more than 10 programming languages, including one of the .NET programming languages, C#.

However, please take note that programming languages such as VB NET may not work (CMIIW) and support only .NET Core.

If you use .NET Core in the program you build on MS Azure, then you only need to do some setup such as downloading the available SDK.

But if you are using VB .NET, or you are using .NET Framework (not .NET Core), maybe you need a little time to make adjustments so that your Function can work properly on Alibaba Cloud.

Please see the image posted below, it should be able to lead you on how to get information about using C# on Alibaba Cloud for Function Compute purposes.

[Alibaba Cloud - How to Navigate to C# Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p53Vx.png)

I hope this answer can be useful for you. Please let me know if you want to know more about how .NET works on the Alibaba Cloud platform, I'd be more than happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, The Alibaba Cloud Function Compute support .NET. You can find it [here](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/112379.htm).

Answer (score 0):

> Function Compute supports the .NET Core 2.1 (runtime = .NET Core 2.1)
>   runtime. Functions are written in C#.

Source: https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/112381.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.879954.24.606f78bbbIbiKp

You can download the Function Compute C# SDK/nuget packages from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Aliyun.Serverless).

For code samples, you can refer to the pages at [C# Handler](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/112379.htm) and [.NET Core runtime](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/112381.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are supporting .NET and you can check Alibaba documentation
https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/53095.htm